# ¿Por qué este código da resultados erroneos?

Tags: python

Este es un código para calcular el cobro de un parqueadero por horas. Pero al ingresar 3, dice que cobrará 30000 pesos, en lugar de 28000 pesos. Si prueban este código con horas mayores, verán que también hay discrepancias entre lo que debería dar y lo que da en realidad.
Gracias.

```
print("Hoy solo entrarán al parqueadero aquellas personas que puedan votar.")
year = int(input("¿En qué año nació usted?", ))
resta = 2020-year
if resta < 18:
    print("Disculpe, usted no puede ingresar hoy")
else:
  horas = int(input("¿Cuántas horas va a dejar el vehículo en el parqueadero?", ))
  total = 0
  if horas < 0:
    print("Por favor, ingrese un número válido.")
  for i in range(horas):
    if i <= 2:
        total += 10000
    if i > 2 and i <= 5:
        total += 8000
    if i >5 and i <= 10:
        total += 6000
    if i > 10 and i <= horas:
        total+= 4000
  print("el total a pagar es: ", total, " pesos.")
```

Comment: eso pasa por que `i` toma los valores de `0`,`1` y `2` los cuales solo cumplen la primera condición

Comment: Además has puesto el año como constante y eso irá cambiando (de hecho ya es 2021, no 2020). Para que no te pase, usa `from datetime import datetime` y luego modifica el `2020` por `datetime.now().year`, que te devolverá el año actual.

Answer (score 1):

La función range, si no le pasas un valor inicial, empieza en 0, por lo que tendrías que modificar las comparaciones para saber a qué franja pertenece la hora...

...o bien modifica el range para que empiece en 1:

```
for i in range(1, horas + 1):
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo siento no puedo entender muy bien como es que calculas el total, tal vez sea por que tengo sueño, pero tu problema se soluciona agregando una variable, para tener el registro de horas faltantes y así poder calcular el total

```py
...
  for i in range(horas):
    h = horas - i #se almacenara las horas restantes
    #cambia la variable i por h
    if h <= 2: 
        total += 10000
    if h > 2 and h <= 5:
        total += 8000
    if h >5 and h <= 10:
        total += 6000
    if h > 10 and h <= horas:
        total+= 4000
  print("el total a pagar es: ", total, " pesos.")
```